# Export data from RocksDb to S3 for ETL purpose

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, etl, rocksdb

My new project uses RocksDb as storage. I would like to run a analysis query on the data in the RocksDb table daily and it will need to scan the entire table. I would like to export the data from RocksDb somewhere such as Redshift/S3 for ETL purpose, but I could not find a easy way to do that. Not sure if I understand correctly, the data in rocksDb are saved in SST file and there is a SST dump tool which can be used to dump the files. Then what should I do to load the data to ETL tool? How to parse the data there? Let's say I would like to dump the data to S3 and query it through Redshift or AWS Glue.

Comment: I recommend you to be more specific, it is a very broad question. It's not clear which ETL tool are you using, if you want as a file in S3 then query with Redshift? We can help you if it is more specific.

Comment: @fernolimits  Yes. I would like to export the data to S3 and use Redshift/Glue to query. Thank you so much!